# Disable download capability in Jupyterhub

Tags: python, nginx, jupyter-notebook, kubernetes-helm, jupyterhub

I am new to setting up a Jupyterhub. We followed the documentation to install jupyterhub in kubernetes via helm. I have been reading that there is no feature in jupyterhub to disable the feature of download files in jupyternotebooks launched. I saw in some forums that this is possible via nginx to route all "/files" to a blackhole. However, it did not work. Below is my configuration.

#### helm config.yaml

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  host:
    - myhost.example.com
```

#### k8 Service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: default-http-backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: default-http-backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
```

#### K8 ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jupyterhub-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"

spec:
  rules:
    - host: myhost.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /user/(*.)/files/
            backend:
              serviceName: default-http-backend
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: proxy-public
              servicePort: 80
```

Comment: You may want to configure Nginx itself to route files to somewhere. It's an Nginx configuration - not a k8s one.

Comment: @Roy2012, I am sorry, can you expound more or give a hint on how we can proceed to this. We installed the jupyterhub via helm based on their documentation - https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Have a look at this link - http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#conf_structure. It explains how to configure Nginx. My guess is that this conf file is somewhere in the Nginx container. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @Roy2012 thanks so much. I got it resolved now. I just created my own docker image which disable the download in the server side. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Cool. Great. Glad I could assist.

Comment: @Yeojin Great that you solved the problem. But _how_? Would you be so kind and share the magic with the rest of us? You could answer your own question here for instance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. But I get the solution from this blog. https://ujjwalbhardwaj.me/post/disable-download-button-on-the-sagemaker-jupyter-notebook/. @LaryxDecidua

Comment: @Yeojin Funny, I have found that blog in the meantime, too and it is indeed working, I built it in already in my app. Thanks for notifying me though :-)

Comment: Cool. Glad you made it work :) @LaryxDecidua

Answer (score 1):

Since v3.1.0 you can disable downloads using a jupyter labextension:

```
# disable downloads from File > Download
jupyter labextension disable @jupyterlab/docmanager-extension:download
# disable downloads from the context menu in the file browser
jupyter labextension disable @jupyterlab/filebrowser-extension:download
```

original github issue: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5274